# Openshift 3.11 + 503 response

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I have setup my web application and I saw my POD was successfully deployed, I have created HTTPS and HTTP route of the service. But when I hit the API, it gives sometime success or sometime 503 status code.

I do not see any issue in the POD and also I have setup health check.

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue.

POD Image :- jboss-webserver31-tomcat8-openshift:1.2

FYI- Right now I am using free version of the OpenShift.

Thanks,
Shailendra Soni

Comment: I am seeing the same since about 36 hours ago. I think it is a problem on the Openshift end alas, it likely only affect the free tier so unlikely to be "a problem" if you know what I mean. Let me know if you find anything that works. I get about a 1 in 4 success rate for an api of mine.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this issue, https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.htm?

Comment: Cheers. Submitted a ticket: Ticket ID: 15475

Comment: @OceanLife Thanks for creating Ticket, can you please give a link to track this ticket.

Comment: Ah all I got was an ID. Sure it maps to a link...somewhere. will keep this ticket posted with any updates.

Comment: They are investigating the issue...

Comment: @OceanLife Thanks for update.

Comment: The issues are now resolved. All green your side?